# Using a fruit or salt-water battery to power a motor

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I´m trying to build a fruit or saltwater battery to power a motor.

From my 8 cell saltwater battery connected in series, I get a reading of 5V or so and 2-3A... but it won´t fire up my 5V DC motor. What am I missing? :)

Comment: You might want to look at the date of posting on that video before making a ... fool... of yourself.

Comment: And you should definitely watch the ENTIRE video. Like, especially the part after 12 minutes.

Comment: Do you get 5V at the same time you see 2-3A ?  I bet not.

Comment: 5V is the open circuit voltage (no current draw), I'm betting 2-3A is the short circuit current (almost zero vpltage across the load - i.e. a short circuit). Your running levels will be somewh lower, try measuring the voltage across the battery when ypu connect the motor, I guarantee it won't be 5V.

Comment: I did this experiment once in intermediate school and figured I'd need a few thousand lemons to power a little boat. Mind you, my setup probably wasn't very efficient (small electrodes, for one)

Comment: Size of each metal plate?   Fifty square inches of area, right?  In a big glass jar?

Comment: I think that your measure of 2-3A is probably wrong. Or, when you were measuring this, the voltage dropped to almost zero. As @gbarry pointed, I doubt that you get both measures at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cold store some energy in a capacitor (which will take some time to load up with only mAmps). If you measure the change of the voltage you can calculate the energy you have collected: Energy [joule=Ws] = 0,5 * C [Farad] * U^2 [Volt]
You can use the collected energy during a much shorter time.

Comment: a capacitor would not help. The motor should run only with the batteries.

Comment: @mguima: Why do you say that? A suitable capacitor would help. Trickle charge it from the lemon. When the voltage is high enough then give the motor a shot. The high initial voltage might provide enough starting torque and the motor would continue until friction overcomes the driving force.

Comment: Here is an example with a Leyden Jar.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvLTJN_1zF0